# Sonarqube history table on multiple projects

Tags: java, sonarqube

The current History Table widget in Sonar only shows the metrics between snapshots on the selected project.

Is there a dashboard configuration/widget to show metrics between snapshots, or over time, for all projects in a single table?

Answer (score 0):

After searching and clicking around SonarQube, I re-discovered the "Measures"-tab. Once there I added the column of the metrics I needed and got the report/table I wanted.